# How to parse TOML in Rust with unknown structure?

Tags: rust, toml

My configuration file has a large number of arbitrary key-value pairs in it, which I want to parse using the toml crate. However it seems as if the standard way is to use a given struct that fits the configuration file. How can I load the key-value pairs into a data structure like a map or an iterator of pairs, instead of having to specifiy the structure beforehand with a struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't need to do anything special other than tell it to deserialize into a `HashMap`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use toml;

fn main() {
    let toml_data = r#"
        foo = "123"
        bar = "456"
    "#;

    let config: HashMap<String, String> = toml::from_str(toml_data).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", config);
}
```

Of course, since TOML and Rust are both typed, your keys all need to be the same type (`String` in this example), and it cannot handle tables, since it wouldn't know where in the map a table should go.

If you do have a couple tables, just add your maps as fields to a struct and that works just as simply:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use toml;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    data_a: HashMap<String, String>,
    data_b: HashMap<String, String>,
}

fn main() {
    let toml_data = r#"
        [data_a]
        foo = "123"
        bar = "456"
        
        [data_b]
        bat = "123"
        baz = "456"
    "#;

    let config: Config = toml::from_str(toml_data).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", config);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`toml` as a [`Value`](https://docs.rs/toml/latest/toml/value/enum.Value.html) struct that can hold anything and that you can introspect dynamically in order to discover any content without forcing the usage of a specific structure.

```rust
use toml::Value;

fn show_value(
    value: &Value,
    indent: usize,
) {
    let pfx = "  ".repeat(indent);
    print!("{}", pfx);
    match value {
        Value::String(string) => {
            println!("a string --> {}", string);
        }
        Value::Integer(integer) => {
            println!("an integer --> {}", integer);
        }
        Value::Float(float) => {
            println!("a float --> {}", float);
        }
        Value::Boolean(boolean) => {
            println!("a boolean --> {}", boolean);
        }
        Value::Datetime(datetime) => {
            println!("a datetime --> {}", datetime);
        }
        Value::Array(array) => {
            println!("an array");
            for v in array.iter() {
                show_value(v, indent + 1);
            }
        }
        Value::Table(table) => {
            println!("a table");
            for (k, v) in table.iter() {
                println!("{}key {}", pfx, k);
                show_value(v, indent + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input_text = r#"
    abc = 123
    [def]
      ghi = "hello"
      jkl = [ 12.34, 56.78 ]
    "#;
    let value = input_text.parse::<Value>().unwrap();
    show_value(&value, 0);
}
/*
a table
key abc
  an integer --> 123
key def
  a table
  key ghi
    a string --> hello
  key jkl
    an array
      a float --> 12.34
      a float --> 56.78
*/
```

Comment: It seems toml::Value is an enum type, why not using match statement.

Comment: @MYLS you are perfectly right. I don't even understand how I wrote that, probably I was so tired ;^) Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

For what is is worth!
I came here to find a way to handle a `toml`-config file for my project.
This is what I've found:

You can parse an arbitrary `toml` file by using the `Table` type.
See [the documentation](https://docs.rs/toml/latest/toml/index.html#parsing-toml).

All types can be automatically parsed but you cannot escape the fact that `rust` is typed. Therefore you have to parse the values into an expected type.

See my example:

```
use toml::Table;

fn main() {
    //Load toml file
    let path = std::path::Path::new("../Cargo.toml");
    let file = match std::fs::read_to_string(path) {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(e) => panic!("{}", e),
    };

    let cfg: Table = file.parse().unwrap();
    println!("Config in table format\n");
    dbg!(&cfg);

    println!("Index into config");

    let cfg_string: &str = cfg["package"]["version"].as_str().unwrap();
    println!("Version: {:?}", cfg_string);

    let cfg_bool: bool = cfg["package"]["nest"]["nested_bool"].as_bool().unwrap();
    println!("Nested bool: {:?}", cfg_bool);

    // Default value if failed
    let cfg_float: f64 = cfg["package"]["nest"]["nested_int"]
        .as_float()
        .unwrap_or(5.0);
    println!("Default float to value: {:?}", cfg_float);
}
```

The `toml`-file

```
[package]
name = "rust_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
toml = "0.6.0"

[package.nest]
nested_float = 1.0
nested_int = 1
nested_bool = false
```

Output:

```
Config in table format

[src/main.rs:13] &cfg = {
    "dependencies": Table(
        {
            "toml": String(
                "0.6.0",
            ),
        },
    ),
    "package": Table(
        {
            "edition": String(
                "2021",
            ),
            "name": String(
                "rust_test",
            ),
            "nest": Table(
                {
                    "nested_bool": Boolean(
                        false,
                    ),
                    "nested_float": Float(
                        1.0,
                    ),
                    "nested_int": Integer(
                        1,
                    ),
                },
            ),
            "version": String(
                "0.1.0",
            ),
        },
    ),
}
Index into config
Version: "0.1.0"
Nested bool: false
Default float to value: 5.0
```